# how to use date picker in angular JS form.?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

how to add date picker in the angularJS form, I have a form and want to use date picker calender . so that after selecting the date from the calender it gets populated in the field.

Comment: Could you provide to us your code?

Comment: Right now I do not have any code. but I have to make a registration form and give a date picker in it so that value could be saved in the data base.@ Artyom

Answer (score 1):

A real favorite of mine is: https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate

Smallest there is and no dependencies.

If you want to try it yourselfs, check out how others have done it. *Basically* you'll expose the scope to a directive and manipulate it from there.

Comment: Can you please write a simple code of date picker in angularJS and its controller ?@petur

Answer (score 0):

you can user angular-ui datapicker

```
   <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
</div>
```

please go through below link
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

it is having all angular controls which we need

you need to download bootstrap.css,ui-bootstrap js and other dependencies.
you also add library in your module like below

```
 angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

everything you need to do is given here :http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: hello, it is not working. Can provide some other solution. Or integrate date picker code and controls.?@Nitu Bansal

Comment: did you download the js required for this??

Comment: I am importing it online by giving link @ Nitu Bansal

Answer (score -1):

This is the best for me https://720kb.github.io/angular-datepicker/

Look so good and works fine

**Edit:**

You can use Datepicker Angular.

You can do this is for Html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
    <input datepicker type="text" ng-model="myDate"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this on javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['720kb.datepicker']);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  var liveDate;

  $scope.$watch('myDate', function (value) {
    try {
     liveDate = new Date(value);
    } catch(e) {}

    if (!liveDate) {

      $scope.error = "This is not a valid date";
    } else {
      $scope.error = false;
    }
  });
}]);
```

And remember to add libraries. 
Hope works for you